# R plot deletes old plots loop

Tags: r, plot

I'm working on a program that generates a grid which changes over time. When I run the code, r creates a plot at the first timestep but overwrites it with the next timestep's plot. I want to plot them side by side.

Full code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8fb71a47caf25a80d5f1c4675804120b

specific loop that's giving me trouble.

```
# plot grid for chosen timesteps 
for (k in 1:length(time)){
    if ((i-1) == (time[k])) {
        par (mfrow = c(2,2))
        plot(NULL, xlim=c(1,nc), ylim=c(1,nr), ylab="", xlab="", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
        title(main=paste("prgrow", prgrow, ": time", time[k], sep=" "), xlab="", ylab="")
        for (a in 1:nrow(A)){
            for (b in 1:ncol(A)){
                if (A[a,b] == "G"){
                    points(b,a,pch=20,col="green")
                }
                else if (A[a,b] == "0"){
                    points(b,a,pch=".")
                } 
                else if (A[a,b] == "x"){
                    points(b,a,pch="x")
                }
            }
        }
        break}
        k <- k + 1 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check [layout function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/layout.html) useful to to define a grid of plots

Comment: BTW, your loop is probably wrong... you shouldn't increase k since you are already looping over k in `1 ... length(time)`